# Symbol 'cout' could not be resolved and #include expects "FILENAME" errors with simple math program in eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse

Every time I create a simple program for eclipse I keep getting the same error:

> Symbol cout could not be resolved, and # include expects "FILENAME or < FILENAME >

I've tried using `#include iostream.h` and changing that to `#include <iostream>`
and adding `using namespace std;` to either version does not solve my issue and adds the problem: Symbol std could not be resolved.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    double radius = 11;     /*Centimeters*/
    double pi = 3.14;
    double sphere_volume = (4 / 3) * pi * (radius * radius * radius);
    double surface_area = 5 * pi * radius;
    cout << "Volume = " << sphere_volume;
    cout << "Area = " << surface_area;
    return 0;
}
```

The console should display the Volume and Area of a sphere with radius 11, but I'm not sure how to get it to accept cout so that it can print that result.

Comment: Your code compiles fine for me. Can you please show command line you use for compilation? Also can you please print the version of your compiler? BTW, `4/3 = 1`, since it's integer division.

Comment: As you no doubt already know, what you have [should compile](https://ideone.com/19aUev) (work as expected is a different issue). Make absolutely certain you are not compiling the program with gcc, a C compiler, instead of g++.

Comment: It sounds like you're building it as a C project instead of C++.

Comment: Is that error message the actual one when changing to `#include <iostream>`? It would make sense before that change but not really after fixing that.

Answer (score 0):

I attempted to use another source to install eclipse, and in the end I had installed a version that did not cooperate with my MinGW. Everything works as intended, thank you for your time.